# how to get the content of web services with angular 2?

Tags: spring, angular

i'm using spring framework in the backend and angular2.4 in the frontEnd . this is the rest service of my backEnd

```
@RequestMapping(value="/etreprises" ,  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Entreprise> getAllEntreprise() {

    return entrepriseDAO.getAllEntreprise();
}
```

and i add CorsFilter  to allow the communication betwen visualcode and STS

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true); // you USUALLY want this
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

and this this the response from the brower

```
[{"id":"58db96c945184728e40fa6f9","name":"entr1","lagitude":15.3,"latitude":12.2},{"id":"58db96c945184728e40fa6fa","name":"entr2","lagitude":15.3,"latitude":12.2},{"id":"58db96c945184728e40fa6fb","name":"entr3","lagitude":15.3,"latitude":12.2},{"id":"58db96c945184728e40fa6fc","name":"entr4","lagitude":15.3,"latitude":12.2}]
```

and i'm working the frontEnd with visualcode

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  entreprises: Entreprise[];
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.http.get('http://localhost:1616/entreprises')
  .subscribe(data =>{
    console.log(data.json());
    this.entreprises=data.json().data;
   });
  }
  constructor(private http: Http) { }


}
```

and the app.component.html

```
<h1>
</h1>
<div *ngIf="entreprises">
<div *ngFor ="let x of entreprises">
{{x.name}}
</div>

</div>
```

and this is the response from inspect element

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

but i can not get the name of the entreprises on the browsers it . a white page without error

Comment: what console.log(data.json()); gives you

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: what each object contains ? try this console.log(data.json()[0]);

Comment: Array[20]
0
:
Object
id
:
"58db96c945184728e40fa6f9"
lagitude
:
15.3
latitude
:
12.2
name
:
"entr1"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
id
:
"58db96c945184728e40fa6fa"
lagitude
:
15.3
latitude
:
12.2
name
:
"entr2"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: try this `this.entreprises=data.json();`

Comment: no changes nothing appears in the browser

Comment: refers to your above reply to Bougarfaoui El houcine, if it shows `Array[20] 0 : Object id : bla bla bla` from `console.log(data.json()[0])` then how about try `this.entreprises=data.json()[0]`

Comment: Object {id: "58db96c945184728e40fa6f9", name: "entr1", lagitude: 15.3, latitude: 12.2}

Comment: it works it was a problem of import of Entreprise class from another project

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try something like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  entreprises: Entreprise[];
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.http.get('http://localhost:1616/entreprises')
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .subscribe(data =>{
    console.log(data);
    //this.entreprises=data.json().data;
   });
  }
  constructor(private http: Http) { }


}
```

Comment: in the console it returns this : [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]